# Get the matches only if the substring is not part of a string

Tags: bash, grep, pattern-matching, string-matching

Hello I actually am looking for a string which is a substring of another string. So I am using grep to get the matches of this string, but the matches of the other string too are coming up.

```
grep -nr 'XML' .
```

when I do this, the matches for string "LIBXMLX" are also coming up. Is there a way to get matches only of XML and no LIBXMLX??

I am newbie to shell scripting, so how do I proceed with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the manual

> The symbols **\<** and **\>** respectively match the empty string at the beginning and end  of  a  word.

So,

```
grep -nr '\<XML\>' .
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-w` switch (exact word match).

Comment: <code>grep -wnr 'XML' .</code>
I get all those results when I use this again!

Answer (score 0):

It's kludgey, I know, but you could use ' XML' as the search string, thereby eliminating anything that doesn't have a space before the X. Just a thought. My interactions with grep are simple.